# c++ set_intersection having different results with same input

Tags: c++, set, intersection

I've been trying to get the intersection of two sets, but for some reason it keeps having different results with the same inputs. The std::set_intersect receives the iterators to two sets (connBuilds, connectedSection): The first has 5 values and the second has 4. 
Here are the values of the sets (containing pointers to a class):

Set 1 :

[image: Set 1]

Set 2 :

[image: Set 2]

The expected result would be a set containing the 4 common values between the sets, but the result varies with each execution. Sometimes, the result is correct, sometimes it isn't.

Here's the code segment where the intersection is done:

```cpp
std::vector<Building *> v;
bool hasHC = false;
bool hasH = false;

ConnectedBuildings connBuilds = invertedBuildingsItr->second;
std::set_intersection(connectedSection.begin(), connectedSection.end(), connBuilds.begin(),
                              connBuilds.end(), std::back_inserter(v));
size_t currentSize = v.size();
```

Here's the struct used for comparing the pointers:

```cpp
struct buildingPTRComp
{
    bool operator()(Building *b1, Building *b2) const
    {
        return b1->getIdentifier() < b2->getIdentifier();
    }

};

typedef std::set<Building *, buildingPTRComp> ConnectedBuildings;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::set_intersection` is unaware of your comparison function, you are specifying your comparator for the set but most of `<algorithm>` functions are just working on iterators as intended.

You should pass your comparator to the function itself too using the proper overload:

```
template< class InputIt1, class InputIt2,
          class OutputIt, class Compare >
OutputIt set_intersection( InputIt1 first1, InputIt1 last1,
                           InputIt2 first2, InputIt2 last2,
                           OutputIt d_first, Compare comp );
```